# Ruby on Rails - Legacy Database Model Associations Gone Awry

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, model-associations

I'm a novice to Ruby on Rails, and for a variety of reasons, I need to use a legacy database that I do not have write permissions for. I have two tables with the following fields:

- Skus: sku_id, name.
- SkuAnalytics: sku_id, data1, data2, data3

  ```
  class Sku < ActiveRecord::Base

      self.table_name = "skus"
      self.primary_key = "sku_id"

      has_many :sku_analytics, foreign_key: "sku_id"

  end

  class SkuAnalytic < ActiveRecord::Base

      self.table_name = "sku_analytics"

      belongs_to :sku, foreign_key: "sku_id"

  end
  ```

SkuAnalytic has no primary key, so I do not specify it. The primary key for Sku is sku_id. I want to be able to run some code like

```
s = Sku.first
s.sku_analytics.all
```

And have that print out all of the analytics data for a particular sku_id. However, what happens now is that `s.sku_analytics.all` returns everything in the sku_analytics table, with the sku_id of sku_analytics replaced with the sku_id of s (even if sku_id from s does not exist in the sku_analytics table).

I'm very confused why this is happening, and have no idea how to fix it!

Comment: That should work by the look of it. Can you see the generate sql ?- try going into rails console and see what gets generated. When I try it I get  SELECT "sku_analytics".* FROM "sku_analytics" WHERE "sku_analytics"."sku_id" = $1  [["sku_id", "1"]] which it what I'd expect.

Comment: Hello! Thank you so much for the help, I realized I was reading my database wrong. This works as expected! Just trying to figure out how to close a question on this site.